# How to auto-embed past 10+ videos from a Youtube channel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube-iframe-api

I am trying to auto-embed videos from a Youtube channel and I have a script that works to embed the first 10 (0-9), but fails on videos past 11. I modified this script from https://codegena.com/auto-embed-latest-video-youtube-channel/ and don't know enough about Javascript to debug and find the issue.

Using print statements, I've found that it seems to fail after the line:

```
    var link = data.items[videoNumber].link;
```

I also don't know if it has to do with the fact that the first 10 videos all have a vnum of a single digit (0-9) and the 11+ all have double digits (10+).

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js> </script>

    <!--This one works-->
    <iframe class="latestVideoEmbed" vnum='0' cid="UCidtzlg-36E3MYzGAlHWMiw" width="603" height="339" frameborder="0" name="frame"></iframe>

    <!--This one fails-->
    <iframe class="latestVideoEmbed" vnum='10' cid="UCidtzlg-36E3MYzGAlHWMiw" width="603" height="339" frameborder="0" name="frame"></iframe>


    <script>
    var reqURL = "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=" + encodeURIComponent("https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=");

    function loadVideo(iframe){
        $.getJSON( reqURL + iframe.getAttribute('cid'),
            function(data) {
                var videoNumber = (iframe.getAttribute('vnum')?Number(iframe.getAttribute('vnum')):0);
                console.log(videoNumber);
                var link = data.items[videoNumber].link;
                id = link.substr(link.indexOf("=") + 1);  
                iframe.setAttribute("src","https://youtube.com/embed/"+id + "?controls=0&autoplay=1");
            }
        );
    }
    var iframes = document.getElementsByClassName('latestVideoEmbed');
    for (var i = 0, len = iframes.length; i < len; i++){
        loadVideo(iframes[i]);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: The data loaded in your $.getJSON function only has the latest 10 videos. You need to modify the request to get the next lot of videos

Comment: I think rss2json converter you are using returns only first 10 items for free (even if youtube feed has more than 10 items)

Comment: try using  something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser parse rss feeds

Comment: That was it, thank you @Luke and @DimitriosDouras!